# Errors in the importing products process

Tags: import, ce-1.8.1.0

Sorry to bother you, but I didn't find any information on this.

I have Magento installed on a server and I'm having problems with the importing process for all products.

I followed the importing process, and used the exported CSV file from Magento and completed it with my product info. But when I imported the file I got errors saying that there is a problem with the type column.

I am using Magento as a cross-platform connection between a big online shop and our fulfillment system so I don't need all the attributes that the database has.

**My question: Do I have to complete each and every column from the table or do I let the unused columns empty ?**

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below are the necessary columns in Magento to import a csv file.

```
1. store(Ex: default)      
2. websites(base)           
3. attribute_set(”Default” or another field set name)                
4. type(Ex: “simple”)                   
5. List item 
6. sku(unique product identification)                    
7. status (”Enabled”)                       
8. weight(yes, it is required... just put “1” if you don’t use it)                    
9. tax_class_id(”None” or another tax class name)                        
10. name
11. price
12. description
13. short_description
```

Furthermore the new imported products can’t appear in your store if you miss some of “non-required” fields like

```
1. visibility (”Catalogue,Search”)       
2. category_ids (At the moment these have to be the internal category
ids. we can get it by exporting some products)       
3. qty, is_in_stock (required to show your products if you enabled the
stock control in the administration area)        
4. Image, small_image, thumbnail if you put the image in media/import.Enter the image file name prepended with a slash. You can use the same image, a large image and Magento will scale it to size for the other images.
```